# Problem with loading GeoJSON file in OpenLayers generated by PHP

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, php, json, openlayers

I'm trying to read some geo-data from PostGIS database using PHP, creating a GeoJSON file and showing it on a base map using OpenLayers.

The PHP code works just fine. The generated data in GeoJSON format is valid (I checked it with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)). When I load the page, the developer tools shows no errors, but also doesn't load any data on the map.

I have just started learning OpenLayers and don't know much about it but saw some examples for this and tried to do the same.

Am I doing something wrong in the Openlayers code?

The code is:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
            {layers: "basic"}
        ),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GJ", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "gj/DB2GeoJson.php",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
                })
            })
        })
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-112.169, 36.099),
    zoom: 11
});
```

and the GeoJson file generated is:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "feature",
    "id": "97",
    "geometry": null,
    "properties": {
        "popn_total": ["97"],
        "boroname": ["Staten Island"]
    }
}, {
    "type": "feature",
    "id": "66",
    "geometry": null,
    "properties": {
        "popn_total": ["66"],
        "boroname": ["Staten Island"]
    }
}, {
    "geometry": ["{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[578620.717363209,4495974.81786636],[578535.357633272,4495915.80999248],[578524.626146389,4495908.44992811],[578475.151658836,4495981.94016235],[578550.53822566,4496033.27562186],[578571.6880873,4496047.75223892],[578620.717363209,4495974.81786636]]]]}"]
}]
```

}

Comment: I presume the php script is hosted on a webserver. Had you checked already the webserver's log? You must to assure yourself the script execution, in the OpenLeayers context, was ok or not. Was the generated GeoJson sent to the browser? If not, what is the cause?

Comment: Yes, the PHP script is hosted on a webserver. when I load the Php page myself the code generated in GeoJSON format appears in the browser, so I guess it is functioning correctly...

Comment: You really must to check the webserver log and to see if it works when loading the OpenLayers code!

Comment: I'm a beginner here. Could you kindly tell me how I can check the webserver log? I'm using IIS on Windows server 2013

Comment: Unfortunately, I've switched to Apache during the dot-coms boom! Let's hope someone else will guide you.

Comment: Can you post the geojson returned or check it with geojson.io

Comment: @neogeomat, thank you for the tip. I've updated the question with the generated geojson file. I also checked it with geojson.io and it gave me the following error: "Invalid Json file: TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object". Do you know what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: I would also suggest that you have a look at the data that is received (either using Google's Developer Tools-Net tab, Firebug, or even fiddler) and see if it is coming correctly.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: Thank you. As I mentioned previously, it seems that the data generated has a problem, but I cannot figure out what the problem could be. Do you have any idea? The error I received is mentioned above. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your generated GeoJSON is valid JSON, no problem. But, it's not valid GeoJson, as you can see here: http://geojsonlint.com/

The problem seems to be that the features-array in your featurecollection contains three features, two with geometry:none and one with just geometry (which is also string-encoded).

So, in short: Your OpenLayers-code seems fine, the trouble is your PHP-code that generates the GeoJSON.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm too lazy to see so deeply ;-) ID:97 and ID:66

Comment: @atlefren: As you mentioned that the generated file is not valid GeoJson. May I ask what is the problem with it? or in another way my question is how does a valid GeoJson file look like? I want to compare and see where exactly is the problem to fix the php code....

Comment: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

Comment: @atlefren: Thanks. Ok. Now I see lots of differences. btw, is the "id":"97" also a problem that should be removed?

Comment: not exactly sure if it's case sensitive, but in most sane computing environments  'A' and 'a' is two different things, so I would guess. id should be fine. Your problem is the geometry: none fields and the feature with just a geometry (quoted as a string)

Comment: @atlefren: You're right, thanks for the tips. I should figure out what the problem is with my php code. I'm marking your answer as correct, since it truly answers the problem I asked for help. Thank you for your effort. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try here: [Integrate GeoJSON file with openlayers.protocol.http](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49491/integrate-geojson-file-with-openlayers-protocol-http#comment65014_49491)

See my answer (the accepted one). The code will solve your problem for sure.

After all, try to access your URL (gj/DB2GeoJson.php) using the browser and check it here : http://json.parser.online.fr/

Check for blank spaces and strange characters (PHP is the winner in messing html things).
Don't forget to see the page SOURCE, not only what the browser shows.

Comment: You're welcome. @atlefren have the correct answer. Your 97 and 66 registers have no geometry, so the OpenLayers have no way to show it. `"id":"97","geometry":null`

Comment: You're right....